# Splitting large pdf based on page range?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

Let us say I have a large pdf called input.pdf and take the page ranges 1-4 5-9 10-13 14-end (say) and put them into individual pdfs called output1.pdf, output2.pdf ... What is the best (and quickest) way for me to do this? I have tried using 'pdftk' but I can't find a quick way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash code (which I wrote after I asked this question). The array pagestarts contains the values of the starts of all the pages. It then puts the required pages into files called test1.pdf, test2.pdf.

```
#!/bin/bash
pagestarts=( 1 5 10 14 20)
i=0
lengthminus=${#pagestarts[@]}
lengthminus=$((lengthminus -1))

while [ $i -lt ${#pagestarts[@]} ]
do
if [ $i -ne $lengthminus ]; then 

y=${pagestarts[$i+1]}
y=$((y-1))
pdftk input.pdf cat ${pagestarts[$i]}-$y output test$i.pdf
else
pdftk input.pdf cat ${pagestarts[$i]}-end output test$i.pdf
fi
i=$((i+1))

done
```